# Typescript - Why a non-optional variable can be undefined in this case

Tags: typescript

if I create a non-optional variable of type "data". Why the value in the next case can be undefined and how can I prevent this from happening and for example throw an error if the value is not really a value? (without manually checking each value in the case that I have many variables inside the type).

`

```
type data = {
  nonOptional: string
  optional?: string
}

var val: string | any = "example"
val = undefined

var data: data = {nonOptional: val};
console.log("nonOptional value: " + data.nonOptional)
```

`
output: "nonOptional value: undefined"

Comment: It's because of the `| any`, which effectively short-circuits type-checking and says that anything goes.  If you define `val` with a proper type `var val: string | undefined = "example"` then you will get the errors that you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as union type collapse

If you try to union a type with another wider type or `any`, it will collapse to wider type or `any`

You can think `any` as the widest type out there

[image]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UBEBDARgYyVAPlAzsAE4CWAdgOYBQA9DVAwHoD8VVokUAQgrLlCjIha9JsyA)

the more narrow a type, the safer it is
(and harder to code, safety always comes with cost)

so avoid `any` if possible, because it is the laziest and least safe type out there

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't use `any`

When you define the type of `val` as the union `string | any` you are saying that it is one of two things: either it's a `string` or it is `any` which is assignable to anything.

You are effectively short-circuiting type-checking of `val` and saying that anything goes.  You can now assign any value to `val`, including `undefined`, because `undefined` is assignable to `any`.

So now let's think about what is happening here:

```
var data: data = {nonOptional: val};
```

We know that whatever value we put on the `nonOptional` property must be assignable to `string`. We know that `val` has a union type `string | any`.  In order to pass type-checking, both possibilities of the union must be assignable to `string`.  `string` is assignable to `string`. **`any` is also assignable to `string` because `any` is assignable to everything.**  Both branches of our union pass, so there is no error.

---

We need to give `val` an accurate type that represents its possible values.

```
var val: string | undefined = "example"
val = undefined
```

The union `string | undefined` covers all possibilities.

When we do that, we get the error that you expect:

```
var data: data = {nonOptional: val};
```

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
>
> The expected type comes from property 'nonOptional' which is declared here on type 'data'

As explained before, both possibilities of the union must be assignable to `string`.    In this case `undefined` is not assignable to `string` and therefore type-checking fails.